# PHP - array_filter with reference Or similar to it

Tags: php

I have an array like below.

```
$a = array(
            array("id" => 1, "name" => "njx", "count" => 0),
            array("id" => 2, "name" => "peter", "count" => 4),
            array("id" => 3, "name" => "jeffry", "count" => 2),
            array("id" => 4, "name" => "adam", "count" => 6)
          );
```

and applied filter like this.

```
$fa = array_filter($a, function ($item) {
    return ($item["count"] > 0);
});
```

then i applied `usort` on variable `$fa`. After that i loop through `$fa` and assigned some values, but they are not get reflected in variable `$a`.

something like below,

```
usort($fa, 'comp');

foreach ($fa as &$t) {
    $t["score"] = 120;
}

var_dump($a); //this doesn't contain "score" field.
```

So my questions is how to get filtered array with original array reference?

Comment: use $a = array_filter($a, ......

Comment: no. then i will lose items having `count < 0`. i need them.

Comment: It would be more easy for others to understand if you show a snippet of output you want.

Comment: As long as array_filter will preserve keys, you could do `foreach($fa as $faKey=>$dummy) $a[$faKey]['score']=120;`

Comment: So it needs another loop over `$fa` and assign `score` based on `id` check? Can't i get filtered array that still hold reference to `$a?`

Comment: You could combine array_map/array_walk with array_filter

Comment: Seems like, your previous option is better than using all this. Just a single loop over `$fa`.

Comment: possible combination of array_filter and array_map `$a = array_filter(array_map(function($x){ if($x['count'] < 1) return false; else{ $x['score']=120; return $x; } },$a));`

Comment: As i mentioned in my question, i need to apply filter then sort then `score`.

Comment: You can't, as simple as that. Continue to work with `$fa`, not `$a`. Why don't you?

Answer (score 4):

array_filter returns a new array and not a reference, thats why any changes applied to $fa wont be reflected in $a.

Instead of using array_filter you could use a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach($a as &$t) {
    if($t['count'] > 0) {
        $t['score'] = 120;
    }
}
```

And then sort using usort.